# Add JavaScript that executes when an image is clicked

Tags: graphics, pdftex, javascript

As explained e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-document-level-javascript-in-latex-documents), JavaScript can be added to a pdf using latex.

Can someone provide me with an example, how I can add a JavaScript to an image in the pdf that executes when the image is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\mediabutton[ 
  jsaction={app.alert('hello world!');}
]{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\end{document}
```